# How do you download files from Github via Batch?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, download, github

So, I am making an "Assistant" that is completely command line based. I recently decided to move from hosting files on One-drive to GitHub. I had made tiny.cc links so it would be easy to change the final url without having to change the batch file itself.

But, as soon as I redirected my tiny.cc urls to my files on GitHub I got errors.
I was using `powershell -Command Invoke-WebRequest http://tiny.cc/sanchitaiexdown -OutFile C:\Users\%USERNAME%\ai\exdown.exe`

And it came with the error could not create SSL/TLS Secure Channel. After a bit of research I found that I had to use this command before it,

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

The issue with this was, it couldn't be run in batch (I want to stay in batch).
So I tried BitsAdmin and it failed me as well.

So, is there a way I can make this work in BATCH. I am fine if an external exe is needed, but it can only be command line and no installation needed.

Thanks

Comment: Your shortened url isn’t https, GitHub only supports, secure connections.  There isnt a point in declaring you support TLS 1.0+ if your not using a https connection.

Comment: I'd actually run `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12, tls11, tls"` and then the `Invoke-WebRequest` command but you can run both of those via batch using a batch script just fine.

Comment: @Ramhound The tiny.cc link is http, but the link it goes to is https.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I just tried that and I came up with an error. Also, I have tried the orignal commands in powershell and they work, but in batch they dont, and I want to stick with batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the **PowerShell** commands via batch by putting the **PowerShell** logic into a dynamically created **PowerShell** script using the [echo](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) command, and then the **PowerShell** script can be executed to run the logic and do whatever you need it to do as in the below example.

---

### Script Example

```
@ECHO ON

:PowerShell
SET PSScript=%temp%\~tmpDlFile.ps1
IF EXIST "%PSScript%" DEL /Q /F "%PSScript%"
ECHO [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12, tls11, tls">>"%PSScript%"
ECHO Invoke-WebRequest "http://tiny.cc/sanchitaiexdown" -OutFile "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\ai\exdown.exe">>"%PSScript%"

SET PowerShellDir=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
CD /D "%PowerShellDir%"
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PSScript%'"
EXIT
```

---

### Further Resources

- [ECHO](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)

Comment: Thanks, I just turned @ECHO OFF to give the script a clean look.

Comment: @user473470 That's just a habit of mine where I like to see everything echo'd.... I'm glad it worked for your needs!!